# I want to buy a medicine

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Today (during a spanish lesson I was doing on my computer) I was presented with:

> Quiero comprar **una** medicina

And its translation as

> I want to buy **a** medicine

The english translation is obviously a direct, literal translation of the spanish, and in this case fails in terms of english grammar.  In english I would "Want to buy **some** medicine" (and in thinking about it I always consider medicine in english to be plural)

But as I am only learning spanish, I don't know if the reason the english translation is so bad is because of:

1. That is not what you would say in spanish
2. The translation itself was wrong (possibly because `medicine` is inherently plural, while `medicina`is singular?)

So which of these possibilities is more likely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Quiero comprar una medicina` in Spanish. Nothing necessarily wrong with that (so discard option 1).

About option 2, you might be right, since you would say "I want to buy **a book**", and pluralize that with "I want to buy **some books**".

Imagine that you could be using that sentence when getting to the counter of the pharmacy and asking the pharmacist for a specific medicine or for help.

> Quiero comprar **una** medicina. *Fluidasa*. Me la acaba de recetar mi medico para la tos.

The tint is that you would say

> Hola, queria comprar **unas** medicinas que el medico me ha dicho que necesito.
>
> Quiero comprar **unos** libros que necesito para el curso que viene.

A Spanish speaker would favor **unas** over **algunas** in that context, in spite of `algunas/algunos` being a possible translation for `some` too.

`Algunos` and `unos` are usually interchangeable, although there could be subtle differences for choosing one or another in a specific context.

Also, I wouldn't over think the translation the computer gave you. Maybe there are more accurate translations (is not a exact science, like math), but I would say that the translation the computer gave you is not necessarily wrong. Just, could be different, such as `I want to buy a (specific) medicine`.

**Edit**:

Also, I remembered how it was for me when I was learning *countable* and *uncountable* in English, so I googled if there any tips about that difference between *algunos* and *unos* and I found [this article](http://spanish.about.com/od/translationsfromenglish/a/algunos-unos.htm). I hope it will be relevant and helpful.

Comment: My problem with the translation is more that is meant to be curated by a human.  99% of the time it makes sense, but for that other 1% I sit there thinking `What are they actually trying to say?`